# Window 7 keep changing my keyboard layout

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ime

I just buy for my laptop a keyboard from eBay ,but because this keyboard is from Asia ,windows keep changing my layout , I just want to use it as an English keyboard ,also I've try lots of methods that non of them works permanently.
Hope you masters can help me solve it out.
Thanks alot.
Guy

Comment: Do you mean an internal keyboard, or an external one? Anyway, have you tried setting the English layout as default, pressing apply, and then removing all other layouts? By the way, have you noticed when exactly Windows changes the layout?

Comment: hey, this is Asus x83v model internal keyboard , windows 64bit English , and yes I've try to set my layout to English as default ,its works for few hours, but then it's seems that something trigger my windows to change my layout.

Comment: So you've set the default to English, but have you deleted the rest?

Comment: yes, this delete them all the others keyBoards.

Comment: And still your keyboard layout changes? So one gets added back to the list? Could you edit your question and add a screenshot of your keyboard layouts when you've removed all except English, and one when your layout has changed?

Comment: Here's some screenshots:
My Bios:
[IMG]http://i40.tinypic.com/rvzole.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Here is the device manager:
[IMG]http://i44.tinypic.com/akeoud.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: @Epsilone3 DaJF meant a screenshot before and after from the keyboard layout settings (like [this](http://i.imgur.com/AkKAcNQ.png)). Not the screenshots you just gave. **There** you need to have **one language** and **one keyboard** setting. You can find it in `Control Panel`>`Regional settings`>`Keyboard and languages`>`Change Keyboards`.

Comment: Hello here is my whole screenshot hope it will help:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_QleDcSYptlY0ZGbHZ5U1hwMEE&usp=sharing

Comment: You still have multiple keyboards listed there. If you only want English, then delete the Hebrew entry there. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

You have selected the English language and keyboard layout. But with (Left-)<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (easily typed by mistake) Windows switches back to Hebrew. This is a setting **which is saved per application**. So even if you change the default the old layout may still be used for some programs.

The easiest way to get rid of the switching of keyboard layouts is (like DaJF already suggested) removing the unwanted language/layout combination.

See the screenshot below. I only have one language with one keyboard layout, so it can't switch to anything else anymore.

You have two choices:

1. You can add the US keyboard-layout to you Hebrew language. This will keep any language preferences of Windows for the Hebrew language but still give you the keyboard layout of an US-keyboard.

   - Click <kbd>Add</kbd> in the screen below
   - Scroll to `Hebrew` and below that choose the `US` keyboard and Add it.
   - Choose at the top `Hebrew - US` as you default language/layout at the top
   - Choose <kbd>Apply</kbd> (otherwise you can't remove `English/US` and `Hebrew/Hebrew`)
   - Click the `Hebrew`-keyboard layout and choose <kbd>Remove</kbd>
   - Click `English` (language) and choose <kbd>Remove</kbd>
   - Click <kbd>Ok</kbd>
2. You can use the `English/US` combination you already added but you'll have to delete the Hebrew-language.

   - Choose at the top `English - US` as you default language/layout
   - Choose <kbd>Apply</kbd> (not needed if it was already the default)
   - Click the `Hebrew`-language and choose <kbd>Remove</kbd>
   - Click <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Now your keyboard will stay in `English - US` (or in `Hebrew -US` depending on your choice above).

---

[image]

Comment: Thank alot Pal , but ,my problem is not switching between Hebrew and English  , my problem is wrong characters while using Hebrew or English.

Comment: @Epsilone3 Then you might want to explain your problem a bit better. What exactly  happens and when...?